# Is the sprouted wheat used in any traditional recipes?

Tags: wheat, sprouting

The healthy food movements uses sprouted/germinated wheat in many ways. They even make sprouted wheat grains bread. But is the sprouted wheat used in any traditional cuisines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the earliest uses of wheat called for germinating the seed as part of the malting process, i.e. making malt in order to make beer. There's archeological evidence shows evidence of sprouted grains being used in malting kilns from the time of the ancient romans.

In addition to beer, other traditional uses of malt, and therefore sprouted grains, include [Samanu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samanu) and [Mammi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A4mmi).

Unlike wheat strains of the modern world, there's evidence that most of the ancient grains would germinate during storage, so it could be most ancient people's default experience with grains were with sprouted grains. Traditional recipes for porridge, gruel, or bread likely used germinated grains and flours.